# Extract fields from pdf itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have this Crystal Reports pdf export. That has multiple pages, every page is one candidate. I need to burst this report to a single pdf from every page. On that page there are two fields (candidate and name) that are part of the new pdf file name. How can I get the fields values from the pdf. The list of fields is empty, count is zero. To be more clear: filename must be concatinated from the field value of two fields on every page.

```
Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)) ', filename)) 'pdfTemplatePath)
        Dim copy As PdfCopy
        Dim kandidaatnummer As String
        Dim naam As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
            ' Filter the dataset for the candidate.
            dataSet.Tables("ReportData").DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Kandidaatnummer = '{0}'", processedCandidates(i - 1))
            ' Create a new dataset for the candidate.
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            ds.Tables.Add(dataSet.Tables("ReportData").DefaultView.ToTable("ReportData"))
            Dim d1 As Document = New Document()

            Dim newFilename As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", tempFolder, FileNameHelper.GetFileName(ds.Tables("ReportData"), "pdf", "DeelRapportage", ReportType.DeelrapportageSubrapporten))
            copy = New PdfSmartCopy(CType(d1, Document), New FileStream(newFilename, FileMode.Create))
            d1.Open()
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i)) ' reader.NumberOfPages - i + 1))

            d1.Close()
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Do the fields on the different pages have different AcroForm field names? Otherwise any PDF processor may consider their values to be identical, too: A PDF has but one Form and each field of the form has but one value. The fields may have multiple appearances on multiple pages but still each form field has but one value.

Comment: The question is unclear because the first sentence does not compute: when you have multiple pages with the same fields, you have multiple pages with the same data because a single field can only have a single value. The question needs to be rephrased to clarify what is asked here. You want to *burst* a PDF and you want to programmatically determine the name of each single page. You want to define that name based on the value of a field on each page, but it is *impossible* that each field on each page has the same name. It can't be `kandidaatnummer` and `naam` for each page.

Comment: Although I wasn’t very clear in the explanation of my question you made the right hypothesis… Bruno, please read the editted post.

Comment: *The list of fields is empty, count is zero.* - That sounds like those are no (AcroForm or XFA) form fields but merely some text pieces with some lines drawn around it or some background applied to it. In that case You will have to try text extraction.